# React Native graphql query with relay not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, relayjs

I'm kinda lost with this issue so any help would be appreciated! So here is the query that I would like to send:

```
query {
  viewer{
    search_places(lat: "40.7127", lng: "-74.0059", searchType:"all", searchTerm:"shopping"){
      edges{
        node{
          id,
          name, 
          lat,
          lng
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

so far so good, this query is working when I try it on GraphiQL. This query returns a PlaceConnection object. Now I tried to implement the same on React Native with Relay:

```
class SearchPlacesRoute extends Route {
  static paramDefinitions = {
    lat        : { required: true },
    lng        : { required: true },
    searchType : { required: true },
    searchTerm : { required: true }
  }
  static queries = {
    search_places: () => Relay.QL`
      query {
        viewer{
          search_places(lat: $lat, lng: $lng, searchType: $searchType, searchTerm: $searchTerm) 
        }
      }
      `
  }
  static routeName = 'SearchPlacesRoute'
}

class SearchPlacesComponent extends Component {
  render () {
    const places = this.props.search_places;
    console.log(places);
    for (var index = 0; index < places.length; index++) {
        var element = places[index];
        console.log(element);
      }
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>email: {places[0].name}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

SearchPlacesComponent = Relay.createContainer(SearchPlacesComponent, {
  fragments: {
    search_places: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on PlaceConnection {
          edges 
          {
            node 
            {
              id,
              name,
              lat,
              lng
            }
          }
        }
      `
  }
}) 

<RootContainer
  Component={SearchPlacesComponent}
  route={new SearchPlacesRoute({lat:"40.7127", lng: "-74.0059", searchType:"all",searchTerm: "shopping"})}
  renderFetched={(data) => <SearchPlaces {...this.props} {...data} />}/>
```

but when I try to grab the data with this I get the following error:

```
1. Objects must have selections (field 'search_places' returns PlaceConnection but has no selections)
       _search_places40zPNn:search_places(lat:"40.7127",lng:"-7
       ^^^
2. Fragment F0 on PlaceConnection can't be spread inside Viewer
       ...F0
       ^^^
```

So I examined what's actually sent to the server:
[image]

and it seems to me that the fragment is sent as a separate query instead of a selection. Any idea why is this happening or how can I avoid this behaviour?

**EDIT:**

here is my final code - hope it'll be helpful for some:
https://gist.github.com/adamivancza/586c42ff8b30cdf70a30153944d6ace9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your Relay Route is too deep. Instead, define your route to just query against `viewer`:

```
class SearchPlacesRoute extends Route {
  static queries = {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      query {
        viewer
      }
      `
  }
  static routeName = 'SearchPlacesRoute'
}
```

Then, inside of your component, define it as a `fragment on viewer`, instead of on `PlaceConnection`:

```
SearchPlacesComponent = Relay.createContainer(SearchPlacesComponent, {
  initialVariables: { lat: "..." /* TODO */ },
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on viewer {
        search_places(lat: $lat, lng: $lng, searchType: $searchType, searchTerm: $searchTerm) {
            edges 
            {
              node 
              {
                id,
                name,
                lat,
                lng
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `
  }
})
```

You'll need to move the variables (`$lag`, `$lng`, etc) to be defined as part of the container, instead of being defined as part of the route. But I think that should fix your problem.

Comment: You're my man @ryan ! Thanks for the infos - I finally managed to run the query now based on your answer. Will post my whole code. One more question though:
You supplied the `edges` field on a connection named `search_places`, but you did not supply an argument necessary to do so. Use either the `find`, `first`, or `last` argument.
Do you have any advice on how should I set these values? Don't this had to be done by Relay automatically?

Comment: So Relay requires you to use a `first` or `last` argument, although GraphQL does not. You'd want to add it to `search_places(first: 100)` for example, to get the first 100 search places. If you want all of them, you can use a work-around like `first: 999999999`.